# Error while bundle install windows 10

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems, bundler

I have windows 10 and the terminal installed, and when I try and run bundle install I get this output:

```
Kalden@DESKTOP-KK2V578:/mnt/c/Users/Kalden/Desktop/ktane_voice-master$ bundle
The git source `git://github.com/watsonbox/pocketsphinx-ruby.git` uses the `git` protocol, which transmits data without encryption. Disable this warning with `bundle config git.allow_insecure true`, or switch to the `https` protocol to keep your data secure.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Using bundler 1.16.1
Using coderay 1.1.1
Using espeak-ruby 1.0.2
Fetching ffi 1.9.10
Installing ffi 1.9.10 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /mnt/c/Users/Kalden/Desktop/ktane_voice-master/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.10/ext/ffi_c
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20180226-330-1hgm5yc.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
/mnt/c/Users/Kalden/Desktop/ktane_voice-master/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.10 for inspection.
Results logged to
/mnt/c/Users/Kalden/Desktop/ktane_voice-master/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/ffi-1.9.10/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing ffi (1.9.10), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install ffi -v '1.9.10'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  pocketsphinx-ruby was resolved to 0.3.0, which depends on
    ffi
Kalden@DESKTOP-KK2V578:/mnt/c/Users/Kalden/Desktop/ktane_voice-master$ sudo gem install ffi -v '1.9.10'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ffi:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.10/ext/ffi_c
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20180226-376-15d5pse.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.10 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/ffi-1.9.10/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you

Comment: The error message says: `Results logged to /mnt/c/Users/Kalden/Desktop/ktane_voice-master/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/ffi-1.9.10/gem_make.out` -- What is in that file? Simply googling whatever error message is there will quickly find you the solution 95% of the time.